# search and find position in large txt file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sed, find, grep

i want to find a position in an large txt-file (187GB) in a linux dist.

Each entry in the txt-file is limited by $$$$ and i want to find the 3396 entry in the file. So i need to count the $$$$ and then when it reaches the 3396.

how could i solve?

greetz

---

ok i will give an example

```
TEXT
TEXT

TEXT
TEXT
<TAG>TEXT>

<TAG>
TEXT
TEXT
</TEXT>
$$$$
```

So my entries looks like in the file. There could be any character between. After the $$$$ the next netry in an newline begin.

Now my question again. I want to detect the line number of the 3396-count of the limiter of the entri

EDIT:

I have the solution:

```
grep -m 3396 -n '$$$$' FILE
```

Gives me the line numbers till 3396 count of $$$$. The last one then is my line of interest

Comment: What's the format of the file like? Are there line breaks in the file? Will the *entry* you're interested in span across multiple lines? Can the delimiter occur anywhere or only at the beginning of a line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to answer it correctly without any sample data, but you can try the following `awk one-liner` to see if it works.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i=="$$$$") count++; if ($i=="$$$$" && count==3396) print $(i+1);}}' INPUT_FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use python (or an other language).

Have a look at http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.finditer

Has the text between the dollar signs a fixed length? If yes, you can use seek() to jump the correct part very fast.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an earlier poster mentioned to use a better language in favor of awkwardly ancient awk, here's a Perl variant that is also *short*. To skip 3395 items, and print the 3396th use

```
perl -e '$/=q/$$$$/;<>while$.<3395;print$_=<>' <foo.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (it is sed but way to slow for such a big file!):

```
for x in {1..4000} ; do echo -e '$$$$\n'$x ; done |
sed -n '/$$$$/{x;s/^/x/;ta;:a;s/x/&/3396;tb;x;b;:b;x;p;:c;n;p;/$$$$/!bc;q}'       
$$$$
3396
$$$$
```

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat simpler `awk` command:

```
awk '/\$\$\$\$/ { if (++count == 3396) { print; exit } }'
```

You could change `exit` to `newfile` if you want to do this to multiple files.

Assuming you want to print the 3396th line that contains `$$$$`; otherwise, what do you want to do when you find it?